# Ubiquity UAP-AC-M-NP and TP-Link TL-SG108PE not playing nice

Tags: ubiquity, power-over-ethernet

I have just purchased a Ubiquity UAP-AC-M-NP and plugged it in to a POE port on my TP-Link TL-SG108PE switch, but it does not appear to power up.    When I plug it in to a Ubiquity proprietary/passive POE injector it lights up.   This happens on multiple ports, and these same ports have no problem powering my Ubiquity U6-LITE devices.

When powered through the Ubiquity POE device is shows up on my dashboard as "Pending Adoption", so presumably it is working fine once powered up.

I have tried multiple cables, same results.

The specs for the Ubiquity device says "The UniFi AC Mesh AP is compatible with 802.3af PoE Alternative A and 24V passive PoE. You can power it with an 802.3af Alternative A compatible switch."

Details for the PoE switch are a little harder to pin down, but the TP-Link site claims

- Equipped with four 802.3af/at PoE+ ports with up to 30W for each port, data, and power can be transferred on one single cable
- Supports PoE power up to 64 W for all PoE ports*

I note the Ubiquity AP talks about **alternative A**.

Questions -

1. Should any unmanaged POE switch be able to negotiate Alternative A?
2. Does my AP sound faulty?

Comment: I have a Ubiquiti AP here on my desk and just use the Ubquiiti POE device with it. Works fine.

Comment: @John What model is it?   (My "UFO" shaped Ubiquity AP's work fine - its only the new one, ie UAP-AC-M)

Comment: Unifi AP AC Lite

Comment: @john Yeah, my AC lites work fine to.  Its just the new one.  I hate Ubiquity's shenanigans with POE (I thought they had outgrown it when they started introducing stuff that worked with 802.3af - but I'm starting to suspect otherwise)

Comment: Just use the Ubiquiti POE device ,   You will save time and stress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an ID10T error and there was nothing wrong with the hardware.  The person who set it up (I'm looking frantically for someone else to blame, coming up blank) had used a non POE powered ports on the switch.

Answer (score 1):

The Ubiquity UAP-AC-M-NP only supports 802.3af PoE variant A (power over 10/100 data pairs, 1-2 & 3-6) or 24V passive PoE. It does not support variant B (power over 10/100 spare pairs, 4-5 & 7-8). Since IEEE PoE standards require a powered device/PD to accept either variant, the UAP-AC-M-NP can be considered non-compliant. Ubiquiti is infamous for using several PoE variants of their own.

Likely, your TL-SG108PE switch uses variant B, so the WAP doesn't work. Using an adapter to swap the pairs won't work as the Autonegotiation needs to run on pairs 1-2 & 3-6.